# How can put what come after the decimal in a integer in java?

Tags: java

For example if I had a (double 123.987) how can take what comes after the right of the decimal and make it A integer (987)?

Comment: So if you have 123.9 and 123.91, do you want 9 and 91 respectively ?

Comment: everything after the ".".

Comment: The "duplicate" is a C# question. How is it related to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use String and split to derive your output:

```
double number = 123.456;
String numberString = String.valueOf(number);
String[] digits2 = numberString.split("\\.");
System.out.println(digits2[1]);
```

After having this output, you can cast it to integer. Should not be that hard